# Getting frequencies from time intervals in R

Tags: r, time

Hope you can help me with my problem.

For example, there is data on people getting on(Time1) and off(Time2) a train. 
What I want to find out is how many people are on the train at a certain point in time, e.g. 2018/01/01 16:00. Looking at the data set, I can see that there are two people on the train at that time. 
In the end I'd like to get a table displaying the date and hour in one column and the number of people on the other. Is this possible in R?

Many thanks in advance!

[image: Demo]

I'm aware I'm not giving you a lot of info to work with. Don't really know how to post stuff with a nice format here...
I don't expect a detailed solution, just pointing me in the right direction would be nice.

Comment: Yes, it is possible but without a reproducible example we cannot help you much. Seems that you need to check for each row if your certain point in time is between the start and end date and then count how many times this is true. This small example might help you: `library(dplyr);
library(lubridate);

x = ymd_hms("2018-01-01 16:00:00");
between(x, ymd_hms("2018-01-01 15:00:00"), ymd_hms("2018-01-01 16:20:00"));
between(x, ymd_hms("2018-01-01 10:00:00"), ymd_hms("2018-01-01 12:50:00"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a small example with 2 people on the train and 2 time points of interest:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# example dataframe (2 people on the train)
df = data.frame(start = c("2018-01-01 10:00:00", "2018-01-01 13:00:00"),
                end = c("2018-01-01 15:00:00", "2018-01-01 17:00:00"), stringsAsFactors = F)

# get a set of time points of interest
times = c("2018-01-01 16:00:00", "2018-01-01 09:00:00")


data.frame(times, stringsAsFactors = F) %>%  # for each time point of interest
  mutate(d = list(df)) %>%                   # join with inital dataset
  unnest() %>%                               # unnest data
  rowwise() %>%                              # for each row
  mutate(flag = between(ymd_hms(times), ymd_hms(start), ymd_hms(end))) %>% # add a flag value if the time point is between the start and end time
  group_by(times) %>%                        # for each time point
  summarise(NumPeople = sum(flag))           # add the flags to get number of users within the time frames

# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   times               NumPeople
#   <chr>                   <int>
# 1 2018-01-01 09:00:00         0
# 2 2018-01-01 16:00:00         1
```